# Google Api Hacked

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I made amistake and installed a Chrome extension and I gave access to my google API to someone who keeps uploading Bitcoin videos to my YT Channel.
Ive changed my passwords but still, what other troubleshooting do you think I must do?

Comment: If it is through the API as you said, then delete the API key. If it is actually an authorization to your account, then check [this article](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en) how to revoke access.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your password won't terminate access to your account from an OAuth token, which is being used to upload to your YouTube channel.

You should be able to remove the app by going to Account > Security > Third-party apps with account access and removing access for third-party apps you don't trust.